# Angular (click) not working after ngFor backing array updated

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

In the [following Angular code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-click-issue), the click event does not fire after `filteredList` is updated:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" *ngIf="showOptions">
    <li *ngFor="let fund of filteredList" >
      <a (click)="selectFund(fund)">{{fund.name}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

`filteredList` gets updated every time the user types something in a text input. Note that the text input is backed by a `FormControl` object, and `filteredList` gets updated when the `FormControl.valueChanges` observable sends new data.

The `<a>` tag list does get updated accordingly, so change detection happens as expected. The only issue is that clicks don't work anymore after every refresh.

The only way to make the `(click)` listener work again is to toggle `showOptions` to false then true through a UI click.

I must be missing something as this should work perfectly fine.

EDIT: You can see the code in action here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-click-issue. Everything is in `app.component.ts` and `app.component.html`. If you select a dropdown element, it works. If you type a filter in the input, then click on a dropdown element, it does not work unless the dropdown gets closed and reopended.

Comment: Do you get new `<a>` tags when your list updates? or you don't get either the `<a>` tag nor the event?

Comment: Yes, the <a> tags are properly updated and reflect the filtered list, which is why this doesn't make sense

Comment: Well everything looks fine to me. You may have to try and make a plunkr to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: I know... Same here, hence the question.

Comment: instead of the ngIf try using [hidden]="!showOptions"

Comment: can you provide a plunkr or similar. code seems fine.

Comment: Any error message in the console when updating `filteredList` or when clicking on the links?

Comment: No errors. Nothing happens.

Comment: I just added a stackblitz link that shows the issue @lexith

Comment: @NadhirFalta [hidden] does not make any difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue came from the following code `(blur)="showOptions = false"` on the input that updates the `filteredList`.

Because of that code, I was trying to do something that was somewhat conflicting (hiding the options as I clicked on one of them), which lead to that side effect.
 I removed the `(blur)` binding and everything works fine!

Comment: Definitely saved my day.. same here. Thanks a lot! :)